# Why is the prop passed to this component/axios not working?

Tags: reactjs, laravel

Hardcoding the URL parameter works but using a variable/prop does not. The database table field is an integer.

This works (no error)

---

```
export default function LocationComponent({ zipcode }) {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [zipData, setZipData] = useState([]);
   

    const getZipData = (url) => {
       console.log("zip", zipcode); 
        url = url || `/zipcode/44366`;
        setLoading(true);
        axiosClient.get(url).then(({ data }) => {
            setZipData(data.data);

            setLoading(false);
        });
    };

    useMemo(() => {
        getZipData();
    }, []);

    return ( ...
```

---

This generates an error (axios.js?v=9f03c4fa:1511     GET http://localhost:8000/api/zipcode/44366 404 (Not Found))

---

```
                
export default function LocationComponent({ zipcode }) {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [zipData, setZipData] = useState([]);
   

    const getZipData = (url) => {
       console.log("zip", zipcode);
        url = url || `/zipcode/${zipcode}`;
        setLoading(true);
        axiosClient.get(url).then(({ data }) => {
            setZipData(data.data);

            setLoading(false);
        });
    };

    useMemo(() => {
        getZipData();
    }, []);

    return (...
```

The is the Laravel api route:

```
    Route::get('zipcode/{zipcode}', function (int $zipcode) {
        return new ZipcodeResource(Zipcode::findOrFail($zipcode));
    });
```

Comment: in the first code example check the network tab in browser devtools to see if the request is same as the second code example

Comment: also is localhost:8000/api where you want you want to send request to ?

Comment: Yes:     GET http://localhost:8000/api/zipcode/44366 404 (Not Found) and the hardcoded is: Request URL:
http://localhost:8000/api/zipcode/44366
Request Method:
GET
Status Code:
200 OK

Comment: @KathyBBB there must be a difference of some kind

Comment: @Konrad I agree but I have tried everything I can think of. Hoping someone sees this who has had this problem in the past.

Comment: @KathyBBB is this API endpoint working on postmen?

Comment: Are you making sure that the url is passed correctly? Can you see in devtools in network tab that the request url is forming correctly with zipcode?